# Textures render very weirdly in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I am trying to draw a box in OpenGL (top is open). I gave it textures but they seem to render very weirdly. The side texture appears to be on the bottom sometimes when I rotate the box and what not.

This is the front view:

[image: Front view]

After rotating it a bit:

[image: Rotated view]

Clearly, something is wrong here. The blue one is the texture for the side panel but when it is rotated, it appears to go on the floor. And the grey one is texture for the front panel. So, in the front view, the back panel shouldn't be visible at all. But, it can be seen.

Code snippets:

Method for drawing the container (lid not included):

```
void box::drawContainer() {
    GLuint tex = loadTexture("wood.bmp");
    glPushMatrix();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    drawBlock(vertex(0, 0, 0), length + 0.2, length + 0.2, thickness); // bottom

    tex = loadTexture("tiles.bmp");
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    drawBlock(
            vertex((length - thickness) / 2.0,
                    (containerHeight + thickness) / 2.0, 0), thickness, breadth,
            containerHeight); // right

    tex = loadTexture("ocean.bmp");
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    drawBlock(
            vertex((thickness - length) / 2.0,
                    (containerHeight + thickness) / 2.0, 0), thickness, breadth,
            containerHeight); // left

    tex = loadTexture("smoke.bmp");
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    drawBlock(
            vertex(0, (containerHeight + thickness) / 2.0,
                    (breadth - thickness) / 2.0), (length - 2.0 * thickness),
            thickness, containerHeight); // front

    tex = loadTexture("lightning.bmp");
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    drawBlock(
            vertex(0, (containerHeight + thickness) / 2.0,
                    (thickness - breadth) / 2.0), (length - 2.0 * thickness),
            thickness, containerHeight); // back

    glPopMatrix();
}
```

The drawBlock method:

```
void object::drawBlock(vertex center, float length, float breadth,
        float height) {
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(center.x, center.y, center.z);
    glScalef(length, height, breadth);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    drawPrimitive(vertex(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5), vertex(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5),
            vertex(0.5, -0.5, 0.5), vertex(0.5, 0.5, 0.5),
            vertex(-0.5, 0.5, -0.5), vertex(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5),
            vertex(0.5, -0.5, -0.5), vertex(0.5, 0.5, -0.5));
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

drawPrimitive method:

```
void object::drawPrimitive(vertex v1, vertex v2, vertex v3, vertex v4,
        vertex v5, vertex v6, vertex v7, vertex v8) {
    drawFace(v1, v2, v3, v4);
    drawFace(v5, v6, v7, v8);
    drawFace(v1, v5, v6, v2);
    drawFace(v4, v3, v7, v8);
    drawFace(v1, v4, v8, v5);
    drawFace(v2, v6, v7, v3);
}
```

And, drawFace method:

```
void object::drawFace(vertex v1, vertex v2, vertex v3, vertex v4) {
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glVertex3f(v1.x, v1.y, v1.z);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glVertex3f(v2.x, v2.y, v2.z);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glVertex3f(v3.x, v3.y, v3.z);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glVertex3f(v4.x, v4.y, v4.z);
}
```

The main function:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50);
    glutCreateWindow(title);

    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutKeyboardFunc(processKey);

    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    initGL();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

initGL method:

```
void initGL() {
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Set background color to black and opaque
    glClearDepth(1.0f);                   // Set background depth to farthest
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);   // Enable depth testing for z-culling
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);    // Set the type of depth-test
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST); // Nice perspective corrections
}
```

loadTexture method:

```
GLuint inline loadTexture(const char* fName) {
    // Data read from the header of the BMP file
    unsigned char header[54]; // Each BMP file begins by a 54-bytes header
    unsigned int dataPos;   // Position in the file where the actual data begins
    unsigned char * data;
    unsigned int imageSize;
    unsigned int width, height;
    // Actual RGB data
    // Open the file
    FILE * file = fopen(fName, "rb");
    if (!file) {
        printf("Image could not be opened\n");
    }
    if (fread(header, 1, 54, file) != 54) { // If not 54 bytes read : problem
        printf("Not a correct BMP file\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (header[0] != 'B' || header[1] != 'M') {
        printf("Not a correct BMP file\n");
        return 0;
    }
    // Read ints from the byte array
    dataPos = *(int*) &(header[0x0A]);
    imageSize = *(int*) &(header[0x22]);
    width = *(int*) &(header[0x12]);
    height = *(int*) &(header[0x16]);

    // Some BMP files are misformatted, guess missing information
    if (imageSize == 0)
        imageSize = width * height * 3; // 3 : one byte for each Red, Green and Blue component
    if (dataPos == 0)
        dataPos = 54;
    // Create a buffer
    data = new unsigned char[imageSize];

    // Read the actual data from the file into the buffer
    fread(data, 1, imageSize, file);

    //Everything is in memory now, the file can be closed
    fclose(file);
    // Create one OpenGL texture
    GLuint textureID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);

    // "Bind" the newly created texture : all future texture functions will modify this texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);

    // Give the image to OpenGL
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_BGR,
            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    return textureID;
}
```

The draw method which calls drawContainer:

```
void box::draw()
{
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);
        drawContainer();
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Please tell me if any more code needs to be inserted or anything needs to be removed.

Comment: I will recommend that you don't use the OpenGL deprecated functions, as I can see, around 70% of all the OpenGL functions you're using, are deprecated.

Comment: We have to use an older version of OpenGL not v4.3

Comment: Why do you "have" to do that? Also, most of the functions have been deprecated since version 3.1 (2009)

Comment: This is part of an assignment and we have been told it should comply with v2.1

Comment: Which kind of school or? tells you to use old technologies? sounds weird, though still keep in mind what I said, for future projects.

Comment: I don't know. The professor wanted it that way. He said it will help to learn OpenGL faster. I have no idea. And I am new to OpenGL

Comment: Okay that I can agree with, since it's "easier" to understand the deprecated functions, though I also want to disagree with that, because then when you need to switch to the new functions it can get tricky because you're use to all the old functions.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. And could you please help me with the problem I have at hand?

Comment: I can try, I will post an answer.

Comment: Can you post the code where you setup your projection matrix? This reminds me of a recent issue that turned out to be an invalid near plane in a perspective projection matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I gave the z-perspective wrong. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2):

It's already said in other answer, though I looks like it's a problem with the `GL_DEPTH_TEST` not being enabled.

Though, yes I do see that your code contains the following:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
```

## Context Problem

I think the problem is that you haven't actually allocated/given any memory to the depth buffer. Thereby the `GL_DEPTH_TEST` can't be performed.

Though I can see that you actually say:

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_RGBA);
```

**Remember:** You need to pass `GLUT_DEPTH` and not `GL_DEPTH`, etc. *(I'm saying this, in case anybody else faces the same problem as you, and this is usually a common mistake)*

Have you tried using:

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA);
```

## Hardware Problem

The problem might also be because of the hardware you're using on the computer, some hardware doesn't support 32-bit depth buffers, thereby you can use 24-bit, etc depth buffers.

## Perspective Problem

I don't see anywhere in your code where you actually set the perspective, this might also be the reason that the depth testing is messed up. Since if you are using `0.0` for the near plane in the perspective projection matrix, well it might mess up the depth testing.

*I apologize for the much open answer, but I'm not able to test this right now. Also if it is happening because of your hardware, then I/we can't test it.*

Comment: I think the only other thing that may cause this on top of the ones mentioned in this answer could be that something somehow calls glDepthMask(GL_TRUE); since not writing the depth buffer results in something similar to not enabling depth test at all.

Comment: @DrakkLord Ohh yea, totally forgot everything about that.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Also, make sure that your OpenGL context has a depth buffer (this is platform-dependent; since you don't show how you create your context window, I cannot show you how to do it).

And finally, make sure to pass `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT` to `glClear` wherever you call it.

Comment: That is there in my init function. I haven't put the code for init function.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit

Comment: What API do you use for window creation? GLUT? GLFW? X11? Anything else?

Comment: And yes, I have also done `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);`

Comment: I use glut. `glutCreateWindow(title)` where title is a string variable

Comment: Pass `GLUT_DEPTH` to `glutInitDisplayMode`.

Comment: That is there too. I'll add my initialisations also in the question.

Comment: Too bad, really looks like a depth test issue, but he seems to do everything right in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not complete, so this is just a guess. (you didn't show loadTexture)

I do not see where you enable and disable textures, therefore the last active texture is going to be used for the rest of the rendering, possibly causing problems.

The proper order of using texture is to enable it, bind to a texture, render, and then disable the texture. Something like this :

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
// render here
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

[OpenGL common mistakes](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes) may help you solve your problem.

---

If you use `box::drawContainer()` to render the image, then you are doing it wrongly, since you are going to create new textures every time the window is rendered. You need to do it once, and then just use the textures. When the textures are not needed, you can release them.

Comment: I enabled glTexture once, did a glBindTexture before drawing every face and disabled at the end. Do I have to enable and disable before and after drawing every face?

Comment: I have also added the loadTexture method.

Comment: @pratnala I do not see where you enable the texture (with `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);`). Yes, you need to enable/bind/render/disable every time.

Comment: This method:

`void box::draw() {
 glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
 glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);

 drawContainer();
 glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}`

Comment: @pratnala you didn't post that

Comment: I am sorry. I added now.

Answer (score 0):

You never seem to clear your color/depth buffer. You need to do it before each frame. Also, be sure that your depth test is still enabled when you trace your container :

```
glIsEnabled( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
```

If not, look in the code you haven't posted.

Hope this helps

Comment: In my display function which I haven't posted, I have this: `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);`

Comment: And initGL in the above code has this: `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);`

Comment: Then everything seems to be fine with your code. Do you have the same problem when tracing without textures? Try one different color per surface and post the snapshot. Because from the 2 snapshots you posted, it REALLY looks like the depth test is not enabled, or the depth mask is 0.